# Overriding Material-UI Select Style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to override the styling applied by Material-UI's `<Select>` component when `variant="outlined"`. For this example, I want the `<Select>`'s dropdown icon to be hidden and `padding-right` to be `0px`.

From my understanding of the [API](https://material-ui.com/api/select/), I should be able to overwrite the styles by passing in `classes={{ icon: classes.hideIcon, outlined: classes.noPaddingRight }}`, where `classes` is:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  hideIcon: {
    display: "none"
  },
  noPaddingRight: {
    paddingRight: "0px"
  }
}));
const classes = useStyles();
```

I am able to successfully hide the icon, but my `noPaddingRight` class is overridden by both `MuiSelect-select.MuiSelect-select` and `MuiSelect-outlined.MuiSelect-outlined` (I'm also confused what the `.` is doing in those two classes):

[image]

The only way I've gotten it to work is by using `paddingRight: 0px !important` but that's something I'd like to avoid if at all possible.

Here is the CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/overwrite-select-style-zqk1r

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use nesting selector for the className **MuiSelect-outlined**

```
hideIconPadding: {
  "& .MuiSelect-outlined": {
    paddingRight: "0px"
  }
}
```

Notice that use `className` here:

```
className={classes.hideIconPadding}
```

---

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help! I guess I always associated the nesting selector with applying pseudoclasses (hover, focus, etc.). I didn't figure to use it to target other nested "normal" elements (thought I had to use the `classes` prop).

Comment: Thanks @andyroo